# Add x number of formated cells based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to format x number of rows based on a cell's value (it gets its value from vLookup). For example if I in cell A1 enter value 3 then I want cell C1, C2 and C3 to get the following values..

```
C1 = "Enter text for row 1"
C2 = "Enter text for row 2"
C3 = "Enter text for row 3"
```

And so on ..

Can this be done using formulas or only by VBA?

Comment: You could do this from either VBA or base-Excel.  The formula version is a probably a little more cumbersome.  You *could* use an if statement that =if(a1<=row(c1), "row 1", "")  then drag it down.  You do that row(c1) so when you drag it will be dynamic to the cell, rather than <=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the green highlighting, use conditional formatting.

Select cell D1 for example as the first cell to right of your "Enter with text" column.

Home --> conditional formatting --> New Rule -->Use a formula to determine which cells to format (bottom option).

In Formula bar type =C1<>""

Don't use anchors (any $'s) on C1!

Then use the format button, bottom right of existing box, Fill tab, select preferred green colour. OK then OK.

Copy cell and drag down to more than cover maximum expected returns of "Enter with text"

Hope that helps

Comment: Glad to help, if you would kindly accept it by clicking tick mark at top left of this answer, I'd appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()>$A$1,"",IF($A$1=0,"","Enter text for row " & ROW()))
```

and copy down as far as the maximum possible value in **A1**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the result is what I was looking for and works as long as I'm on the first row. Do you know how I can make this work if the A1 vlaue would be in G3 instead and the "Enter text for row xx" would be in D7 and below?

Comment: @MTplus  If you want the same stuff starting in cell **D7**, use `=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$G$3,"",IF($G$3=0,"","Enter text for row " & ROWS($1:1)))`

Comment: Thats pretty dope, Thanks!

Comment: If one would want to be a little fancy and highlight the cell to right of each "Enter text for row xx" with a green fillcolor, would that be possible?

Comment: @MTplus  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Thanks, that would be awsome